# Wrapper for consumer bean in spring cloud stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

Assuming I have this code:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ConsumerConfig {

  private final Service service;
  private final Repository repository;

  @Bean
  Consumer<Event> consumer() {
    return event -> {
      repository.findById(event.getId())
          .ifPresent(service::updated);
    };
  }
}
```

It reads an event from rabbitmq topic (configurated in the application.yaml) and calls some service. For that I am using

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Is there any possibility to wrap around this consumer with aspect/wrapper? I need to add additional functionality for each consumer call (for each thread) and I will have a lot of consumers and don't want to duplicate code for that.
It should be something similar to filters on API level.

**UPD**

I've used an aspect, but is there any better way?

```
  @Pointcut("within(my.package..*) && execution(java.util.function.Consumer+ *(..))")
  public void allEventConsumers() {
  }
```

Comment: You can simply do it with function composition instead of AOP. Basically compose your consumer as such when providing `spring.cloud.function.definition` property 
 - `allEventConsumers|consumer ` . Assuming `allEventConsumers` is a Function so it can provide output to the `consumer`

Answer (score 0):

I would have some bean which will be responsible for wrapping/enriching these consumers with side effect code.
You can use function composition or a new consumer to enhance the original logic.

```
//Event class
public static class Event {}


// A wrapper bean
@Service
public static class AllConsumerWrapper {
    public void processEvent(Event event) {
        
    }
    public Consumer<Event> register(Consumer<Event> eventConsumer) {

        return ((Consumer<Event>) this::processEvent)
                //do our work before original eventConsumer
                .andThen(eventConsumer);
    }
}

@Bean
Consumer<Event> consumer(AllConsumerWrapper allConsumers) {
    return allConsumers.register(event -> {
        //originial consume
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I wanted to avoid this exact thing and leave my consumer beans out of knowing that they are processed/wrapped